# How to know which chrome extension changing the webpage

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I have installed some extensions for my use. And when I search something on Google, some extension includes some results (ads) in the search result. 
How Can I find out the extension?

One way is to disable extension one by one to check which is responsible for it.

But is there any better solution for this?

Can I find out **which extension** exactly making changes (**and what changes**) on my webpage?

*(If it is duplicate, please paste the link into a comment before downvoting the question, I'll delete my question immediately. I have made my effort in searching for the answer.)*

Comment: The only way is to disable extensions and test if it is gone or not. The quickest way is to first disable all extensions of which you are sure that are not the cause of this, then test that its still there. Then disable half of the unsure ones and test again. If it is gone, its one of those you disabled. If its there, it sone of those that you did not disable. Either enable few of those you disabled to get the ads back, or disable more to get rid of them and quickly you will find the extension that causes it. Then test by having everything but that extension enabled.

Comment: You already mentioned how to figure it out. Reading the descriptions of said addons hopefully would also give you a clue. But as it is right now you'd have to test it on your own. Also, depending on the format, you might be able to have a look at the source - but it's likely faster to just test it.

Comment: The extension is so smart, it does not include result always, it only includes when I search something that gives some unpopular sites. For example, if I search **facebook** on google, it won't include anything. But say if I search **buy a table saw**, it includes some results. It is ensured as those results are included after some seconds the main page has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of, is to disable extensions and test if it is gone or not. The quickest way is to first disable all extensions of which you are sure that are not the cause of this, then test that its still there.

Then disable half of the unsure ones and test again. If it is gone, its one of those you disabled. If its there, its one of those that you did not disable. Either enable few of those you disabled to get the ads back, or disable more to get rid of them and quickly you will find the extension that causes it.

Then test by having everything but that extension enabled.

Note, it is possible more than one extensions cause for this. If this is the case, you will need to keep disabling extensions until its gone, then add extensions until you see them again.

In that case, I advise to start with disabling the extensions you expect the most to cause for this, keeping the ones you know for sure to not cause this enabled. Don't be surprised if it turns out that the extension you expected not to cause this is actually causing this. Also, start with disabling extensions added lastly. Keeping extensions that were added a long time ago active.